# Can't get value from a javascript class

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    function Group(label, children) {
                        this.label = ko.observable(label);
                        this.children = ko.observableArray(children);
                    }

         function getGroups() {
                        var grps = [
                            [new Group("Group 1", [])],
                            [new Group("Group 2", [])]
                        ];
                        for (var a in grps) {
                            alert(a.toString()); // works, alerts index
                            alert(a.label()); // doesn't works. should give Group label
                        }
                        return grps;
                    }
getgroups();
    });
```

when i try to call getGroups() function the alert is not working. I don' know what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
alert((grps[a])[0].label)
```

Reason:

- `for in` loops through the property keys. In your example all index
  of grps array.
- to reach the object stored in the grps array use grps[a]

How about declaring it like:

```
 var grps = [
                new Group("Group 1", []),
                new Group("Group 2", [])
            ];
```

and then use

```
alert(grps[a].label)
```

It is lot more readable

Comment: Oh, just noticed you are inserting array inside the grps array. You will need to use `alert((grps[a])[0].label)`

Comment: oh now i understand... why its not working. it is because the `this` modifier is actually of the document not of the `Group`.

Comment: That is incorrect. It will point to the group only. You had used grps as a Javascript array. Inside that you had put 2 elements, each being an array. Your structure was giving you nested array. I modified your code in second part of my answer, to remove the nesting.

Comment: In JS when you call like `obj.fn()`, `this` points to `obj`. If you can `fn()` than `this` will point to `global (window)`

Comment: Try alert((grps[a])[0].label())